# Hiding an element via a script in the <head>, then showing with a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm hiding an element, to be shown later when the user presses a button.

I've put this in my head tag in the .html:

```
<script>document.getElementById("answerPanel").style.display = "none";</script>
```

then when a function is called in the .js:

```
document.getElementById("answerPanel").style.display = "";
```

Is this method going to cause a brief flash of the element on page load? Is there a much better way to do this that is (almost) as simple?

Please note that I am trying to avoid using jQuery until I have a solid grasp of vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Why not use plain CSS to hide it? And your script method won't work in the head because the element it refers to hasn't been rendered yet. You'd need to place it after the element is rendered which would cause a flash.

Comment: To avoid the flash, you can set the style inline

Comment: I think it will depend on the browsers. On some, you could see a "flash". You should use CSS to initialize it as hidden. And to unhide it, use style.display = "block" or style.display = "inline". An empty string is not a good practice

Comment: For whatever reason, when I hide using CSS, the JavaScript doesn't work any more. But the script in the head works.

EDIT: Thanks sebcap26, will try that instead.

Comment: That's because using css doesn't add the style inline. When you change it via javascript it's really just adding an inline style.  So if you want hide using CSS, then you have to unhide by changing the display to "block" or "inline-block" or whatever serves your purposes better.  Which is why I suggested adding the initial style "inline" so that your js will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure the element doesn't appear at all at the start, you should set the style of the element via HTML not JavaScript. This makes it so the element is hidden even if requests to other resources like JavaScript files or CSS files are delayed.

Inlining JavaScript could be a solution, and in this case you won't have a problem with it, but if you try to use it for some more complex situations you might run the risk of layout trashing which delays your initial page load. I would not recomend it.

HTML:

```
<div id="test" style="display:none"> </div>
<button onclick='show()'>Show!</button>
```

CSS (optional):

```
#test {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

JS:

```
function show() {  
  document.getElementById('test').style.display = '';
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/oYiDEJU/2/edit

EDIT: This solution (inline style) allows you to change the display value from CSS easily:

```
#test {
  display:inline;
}
```

Hiding and showing it will keep the `'inline'` value, not override it with `'block'`. You can see the issue i am talking about in the linked JsBin.

Answer (score 1):

Hide it initially with css:

```
#answerPanel { display: none; }
```

And then show it on demand with JS:

```
document.getElementById('answerPanel').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. The empty string was the issue with using CSS. Is this a situation where it might be better to use visibility rather than display?

Comment: If you want the browser to display whitespace where #answerPanel would normally be (but still be hidden), then use visibility.  If you want it to collapse completely and not show at all, use display.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid "a flash", the best will be that the browser loads the element already hidden:

```
<div id="answerPanel" style="display: none">
</div>
```